# failed svn commit from xcode when svn repo mounted on mac's filesystem

Tags: svn

I'm trying to use svn 1.6 with my Xcode projects on lion. The server is a tortoise svn server on windows. I can check out the projects with no problem, but when I go to commit I get the error that

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: Can't get exclusive lock on file '/Volumes/SVN_Repository/Mobile/db/txn-current-lock': Operation not supported

The repository is fine. When I go to commit something to the same place with my windows client it works great. The windows client is 1.6.11 and the mac client is 1.6.12 I wouldn't think that would be that big of a deal.

Is there a way to make the mac client work nicely with the windows server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be accessing the SVN using a network share which isn't recommended. It would be better to run an SVN server on the windows machine.

[VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/) is an easy to install option to set up a server on a windows machine.